# SDL Web 8.5 and SQL Server Web Support

Tags: sql-server

I'm just wondering if SDL Web 8.5 works on the lighter version of SQL server (Web).

From what I can tell from this image (https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-1dc2107577c41dd54ca3f61347ba1bdc) there's nothing in here to suggest it isn't possible, but I'm wondering if this version compatible.

From the docs I see that official support is for Microsoft SQL Server 2016 SP1 (Standard Edition or Enterprise Edition) only.    Anyone had a play / test with SQL Server Web ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per pretty much any question ever about SDL Web, it can be answered by [this blog post](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/creating-a-simple-sdl-web-8-dxa-environment).

Long story short, I set up Web 8 with SQL Express, which is an even lighter version of SQL than SQL Web (according to your chart).  Mind you, I was working with Web 8.1.0, which doesn't specify explicit requirements for the Standard or Enterprise Edition. But my gut tells me that it will work for 8.5 as well, since the edition generally only specifies limitations of your databases, with the very basic functionalities the same regardless of which specific edition is used.

Answer (score 2):

Recommended prerequisites
SDL recommends one of the following database servers:

Oracle Server 12.1.0.2 (Enterprise Edition)
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 SP1 (Standard Edition or Enterprise Edition)
Microsoft Azure SQL Database
AWS RDS-MSSQL 2016

If your implementation uses MSDTC, then you cannot use the Cloud database servers, that is, Azure or AWS RDS-MSSQL.

Supported Microsoft SQL Server databases
Content Manager supports the following Microsoft SQL Server databases.

Supported:
SQL Server 2016 SP1 (Standard Edition or Enterprise Edition)
Deprecated:
SQL Server 2014 SP2 (Standard Edition or Enterprise Edition)
SQL Server 2012 SP3 (Standard Edition or Enterprise Edition)
You can download Service Packs for SQL Server from the following locations:
Service Pack 3 for SQL Server 2012: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49996
Service Pack 2 for SQL Server 2014: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53168
Supported Oracle databases
Content Manager supports the following Oracle databases.

Supported:

Oracle Database 12c patch set 12.1.0.2 (Enterprise Edition)

Oracle Database 11g Release 2 patch set 11.2.0.4 (Enterprise Edition)

Deprecated: No Oracle databases are deprecated.

Supported Cloud-based databases
Content Manager supports the following Cloud-based databases.

Supported:

Microsoft Azure

AWS RDS-MSSQL 2016

Deprecated:
AWS RDS-MSSQL 2012

Cloud hosting
To host SDL Web databases in the Cloud, you can use the following hosting services:
Amazon RDS (Relational Database Services) (for Microsoft SQL Server)
Microsoft Azure
PowerShell
To install SDL Web databases on a Windows machine requires Windows PowerShell 3.0 be installed on that machine.

You can download Microsoft Windows Management Framework 3.0, which includes Microsoft Windows PowerShell 3.0, from this location: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595

.NET
To install the Content Manager database on a Windows machine, Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 or higher must be installed on that machine.